# 'Set as interpreter' for a .py file in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ros2

During the execution of one of the examples, the video tutorial in VS Code indicates the message `Set as interpreter`, which allows you to explicitly specify which interpreter should be used for the py file.

[image]

My VS Code doesn't have this message and it doesn't appear even after I type "#!"

[image]

The environment in which I work is fully consistent with that in the video tutorial (VirtualBox , Ubuntu 20.04, VS Code, Extensions)

Are there any other settings that need to be added to VS Code?

Comment: Can you show the video tutorial?

Comment: it must be some extension that generates some codelens for `#!` sequences, is it to SET the default interpreter for the current workspace or to change the path in the `#!` to a different interpreter

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT, unfortunately this video tutorial is paid and available on udemy. I can share the link, but you just won't be able to see it until you buy it

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/497